# How to do logging in aiohttp handlers? (Not Access Logs)

Tags: aiohttp

I am looking for a simple example of how to use `aiohttp.server` error logging in request handlers. For e.g: how can I log an error when a request is made to non-existent route (e.g: `http://127.0.0.1/none`).I know I can see 404 errors in access logs but want to log errors within handlers
Can I use `aiohttp` format specification macros in the error logs?